# Aurelia DI get instances of class by abstract base and or interface

Tags: javascript, typescript, aurelia

I understand this might be outside the scope of Aurelia's DI container but maybe not.

I want to be able to randomly return an instance of any class that inherits from an interface.

For example, I have...

```
interface MonsterRecipe

class KoboldRecipe implements MonsterRecipe

class GoblinRecipe implements MonsterRecipe
```

The first part of this is to get hold of an array of classes to randomise from.

I tried `let allRecipes = container.getAll(MonsterRecipe)` but it is returning 0 items.

I suspect I may need some explicit registration?

If this is entirely flawed...
Is there any other way I can get a random GoblinRecipe or KoboldRecipe when i ask for a `MonsterRecipe`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can explicitly put them in an array:

```
export const RECIPES = [KoboldRecipe, GoblinRecipe];
```

And at configuration time:

```
container.registerHandler(MonsterRecipe, (container, key, resolver) => {
    let random = RECIPES[Math.floor(Math.random() * RECIPES.length)];
    return new random();
});
```

(not singletons here)

--edit:

Building the array using a small decorator:

```
export const RECIPES: Function[] = [];

function randomRecipe(target: Function) {
    RECIPES.push(target);
}

export class MonsterRecipe {
    getName() {
        return "nothing";
    }
}

@randomRecipe
export class KoboldRecipe extends MonsterRecipe {
    getName() {
        return "KoboldRecipe";
    }
}

@randomRecipe
export class GoblinRecipe extends MonsterRecipe {
    getName() {
        return "GoblinRecipe";
    }
}
```

Comment: This would let me use the container. But was hoping to get away from building up my own array of recipes. :(

Comment: Not sure it is possible with TypeScript or aurelia. I added an example using a decorator, maybe a bit more elegant (just noticed I used a class instead of an interface for MonsterRecipe but it work the same way).